# Let $F$ be a field. Why is $\frac{F[x]}{(x-1)}\oplus \frac{F[x]}{(x-1)}$ not isomorphic to $\frac{F[x]}{(x-1)^2}$ as $F[x]$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $F$ be a field. Why is $\frac{F[x]}{(x-1)}\oplus \frac{F[x]}{(x-1)}$ not isomorphic to $\frac{F[x]}{(x-1)^2}$ as $F[x]$-modules?

My initial thought was to say the direct sum is generated by 2 elements but the other one is generated by 1. Is there any truth to this line of thinking?

Comment: In other words, your attempt implies that $R/I\times R/I$ is not a cyclic $R$-module. This is true! Suppose the contrary. Then there is an ideal $J$ of $R$ such that $R/I\times R/I\simeq R/J$ as $R$- modules. Then $I=J$ (why?). Now the isomorphism is of $R/I$- modules, and this is a contradiction with the rank of free modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R/I\times R/I\simeq R/I^2$ as $R$-modules, then they have the same annihilator, so $I=I^2$ (which in your example is not the case).